# change viewcontroller in a tabbarcontroller according to condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app in which the user can skip login. Inside there is a uitabbar controller in which one of the viewcontrollers shows user profile if the user is logged in. But if the user skips login, clicking on the profile tab must show the login screen. How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below `code`, set `BOOL variable` as per your need. For more info. you refer [This link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)

```
BOOL isLogin;
NSMutableArray *tbViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];

UIViewController *message = [[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageViewController" bundle:nil] ;
[tbViewControllers addObject:message];
if(isLogin){
     UIViewController *profile = [[ProfileVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileVC" bundle:nil] ;
    [tbViewControllers addObject:profile];
}else{
    UIViewController *LoginVC = [[LoginVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginVC" bundle:nil] ;
    [tbViewControllers addObject:LoginVC];
}


UIViewController *more = [[[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[tbViewControllers addObject:more];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tbViewControllers];
```